# Read data from a specific column value in a dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

**Context:** I have around 2.000 parquet files in a S3 Bucket. This data has arround 20 columns and one of them is called ***restaurant_id*** and I need to retrieve whole data for each restaurant_id. The data of a particular restaurant_id, I must create a json file, it means for each restaurant_id, I will have a json file.

**What I did so far:** I started using pandas library but I got stuck because after reading the parquet file number 700, I got the error lack of memory. I found on internet, I should use dask library because I can handle more data than pandas library. That is why I implemented the following code:

```
def read_parquet_files_with_dask(bucket_name: str, 
                       access_key_id: str,
                       secret_access_key: str,
                       prefix: str,
                       columns_to_delete: list) -> DataFrame:

  
  s3_path = "s3://" + bucket_name +"/" + prefix + "*.parquet"
  
  dask_df = dd.read_parquet(s3_path,
                            engine='pyarrow',
                            index='restaurant_id',
                            calculate_divisions=True,
                            storage_options={
                                                'key': access_key_id,
                                                'secret': secret_access_key
                                              })


     print(dask_df)
      dask_df = dask_df.drop(columns_to_delete, axis=1)
       
      return dask_df

def main():
## some stuff before
df = read_parquet_files_with_dask(bucket_name,access_key_id,secret_access_key,prefix,columns_to_delete)  

    unique_ids = df.divisions
    print(unique_ids)
    for group_value in unique_ids:
      group_df = df.get_partition(group_value).compute()
```

**Issue:** When I retrieve all the divisions of the dask dataframe, all the values are `none`. I do not know what I am doing incorrectly here. My idea was to retrieve the divisions from the dask dataframe, it means all the restaurant_ids (ie. 1,2,3,4...) and then with `get_partition` I retrieve the data for this particular restaurant_id. Finally, I export this data to a json file. How can I achieve this goal?.

**Update 2:**
I forgot to mention, the parquet files are compressed. The extension of the files are XXX.gz.parquet. Could it the reason why I am getting the values as `none`?. I changed in my `s3_path` variable with *gz.parquet, but still I got the same issue.

Comment: There are several problems in your code: is restaurant_id stored as an index in PArquet files? You should read only the columns you need, and not drop the others after reading. divisions are note the same as unique values of a column. If divisions are none, then there is probably no metadata about it in Parquet. Looping on ids to gather each result is probably a bad idea. I think what you want to do is a groupby over restaurant_id and then build you json.